# Might have overcomplicated my web scraping (R)

Tags: r, web-scraping

To make an incredibly long story short, I have been trying to scrape data from https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/advanced/, and after the API key I found kept crashing my RSTudio, I tried to pull using the query string parameters the website was pulling the data from.
I'm still relatively new to this so it might not even be the necessary method, but my code below keeps returning either 400 or 500 status codes and I can't figure out how to fix the error(s):

```
av_date_beginning <- "12/01/2021"
av_date_end <- "12/31/2021"
min_played <- 100
min <- paste0("Min*GE*",min_played)
group_quantity <- "5"
init_link <- GET("https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashlineups",
                 add_headers("Host" = "stats.nba.com",
                             "Origin" = "https://www.nba.com",
                             "Referer" = "https://www.nba.com/",
                             "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36",
                             "x-nba-stats-origin" = "stats",
                             "x-nba-stats-token" = "true"),
                 
                  query=list("Season" ="2021-22",
                             "Conference" ="",  
                              "DateFrom" =av_date_beginning, 
                              "DateTo" =av_date_end, 
                              "Division" ="", 
                              "GameID" ="", 
                              "GameSegment" = "", 
                              "GroupQuantity" =group_quantity, 
                              "LastNGames" ="0", 
                              "LeagueID" ="00", 
                              "Location" = "", 
                              "MeasureType" = "Advanced",
                              "Month" ="0",  
                              "OpponentTeamID" = "0", 
                             "Outcome" = "", 
                              "PORound" = "0", 
                              "PaceAdjust" = "", 
                              "PerMode" ="PerGame", 
                              "Period" ="0", 
                              "PlusMinus" = "N", 
                              "Rank" = "N",
                              "SeasonSegment" = "", 
                              "SeasonType" = "Regular Season", 
                              "ShotClockRange" = "", 
                              "TeamID" = "0", 
                              "VsConference" = "",
                              "VsDivision" = ""
                    
                  ))
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?  Am I missing a few parameters for this pull or is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Comment: You really should show the actual errors you got. What you told us really doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I'm getting a "Status: 400" error on my GET function.

When pulling content from the GET function using: 
pull_init <- content(init_link, as= "parsed")

it just says "An error has occurred."

Answer (score 0):

Approcah is fine. Yes you need all those parameters. Almost everything looks fine, but you're missing one of the required paramter values.

try changing `"PaceAdjust" = ""` to `"PaceAdjust" = "N"`